# Image causing white space and horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

By ghosting my CSS elements I can see that my mouth image is creating addtional white space but I dont know how to remove it. I've tried hiding the overflow in the hope that it might work but it hasnt? Link to [codepen](http://codepen.io/EndaM/pen/QdqQGR)

```
.mouth{
top: 268px;
left: 273px;
position: relative;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute positioning instead.

```
.trumpframe{
    position: relative;
}

.mouth {
    position: absolute;
}
```

You'll need to tweak the top and left values since I can't see the image it has to overlap.